# font-face url não carrega

Tags: html, css-font-face

Antes de mais nada, já aviso que não encontrei nada nas buscas que pudesse resolver meu problema.

Estes são os caminhos das pastas e arquivos:

```
_pasta_da_html
    pagina.html
arquivo_da_fonte.ttf
css_com_font_face.css
```

Na CSS, meu código está assim:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: "nome_da_fonte";
    src: url("arquivo_da_fonte.ttf");
}
```

Enquanto no HTML, o código está assim:

```
<link href="../css_com_font_face.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<style type="text/css">
    .fonte{
        font-family: nome_da_fonte;
    }
</style>
<div class="fonte">Testando... 1... 2... 3...</div>
```

Eu já verifiquei diversas vezes o caminho percorrido e está correto, mas mesmo assim não funciona, e não, não estou usando nenhum servidor php, apenas o html puro.

Comment: Qual servidor Web (IIS, Apache, etc.) você está utilizando?

Comment: Eu uso apenas o WAMP, mas no caso aí, é pra algo diferente que eu tô testando, e que possivelmente este erro também esteja ocorrendo nos servidores, daí eu estou na dúvida

Comment: @Rick abra a pagina no Chrome e aperte o F12, veja se ele aparece alguma mensagem no console do Chrome, geralmente isso ajuda bastante a resolver os problemas, se tiver alguma mensagem lá que você não compreender, poste aqui para nós analisarmos.

Comment: Eu pergunto porque transmissões de conteúdo podem falhar se o tipo for desconhecido / não registrado no servidor web.

Comment: Apareceu isso: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND ... mas no caso, o arquivo existe, inclusive eu já tentei usar diversas maneiras de mudar o path dele, mas nada que pudesse resolver, com exceção de manter ambos na mesma pasta, o que não é o caso

Comment: Você consegue acessar esse arquivo pelo navegador utilizando esse caminho direto?

Comment: sim, consigo, mas nada até agora